# Primary key is null when left join is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, left-join, rails-activerecord

When I use this request

```
@questions = Question.joins("left join answers as a on a.user_id = #{current_user.id} and a.question_id = questions.id").select('questions.*, a.*')
```

`Question.id` is null. Does anyone know why? Maybe it needs an alias or something like that.

My schema:

```
class Answer:
  belong_to: User
  belongs_to: Question
end

class User:
  has_many: answers
end

class Question:
  has_one: answer
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because of the ID columns of two tables conflicting with one another.

**Update:**

Simply changing the order of select columns will help. So instead of `.select("questions.*", "answers.*")`, try `.select("answers.*", "questions.*")`.

**Old answer:**

Try the following:

```
# Assuming the following:
#   Question.table_name == "questions"
#   Answer.table_name == "answers"

question_columns = Question.column_names # or %w{questions.*}
answer_columns = Answer.column_names.map { |c| "answer_#{c}" }
columns = question_columns + answer_columns
@questions = 
  Question.
  joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN answers ON (
    answers.question_id = questions.id
    AND
    answers.user_id = #{current_user.id}
  )").
  select(*columns)
@questions.first.id #=> should return some integer
@questions.first.answer_id #=> may or may not return something
```

However, unless you absolutely need a `LEFT JOIN` along with those select-columns, it would be much cleaner to accomplish your task using the following:

```
class Answer
  belongs_to :question
end

class User
  has_many :answers
  has_many :questions, through: :answers
end

current_user.questions
```

Comment: In addition to those, you can easily add the `has_many :questions, through: :answers` to your `User` model, and things will work as I described - no database changes will be required.

Comment: But then 

current_user.questions will only returns the questions that have been answered.

Comment: Of course. I mention this in my answer that `unless you absolutely need a LEFT JOIN along with those select-columns`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the answers table probably also has a column named `id`, which is shadowing the question's id. Although in the result set one column is called questions.id and the other a.id, active record just looks at the last part ('id')

There's no good way around this that I am aware of other than aliasing problematic columns from the answers table, which unfortunately means explicitly naming all of them (although you can of course automate this to an extent)

Comment: Good analysis. But I'd like to add that the "explicitly naming all of them" part can be made a lot easier with `Model.column_names.map` as I've shown in my response.

Comment: Sure - I was mostly thinking about the fact that there is no way in sql to say everything but the id column

Comment: Found a very simple workaround for this particular case: simply change the order of select-columns. :P I've updated my answer to include this.